# Modal button loop in calendar dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using FullCalendar and I want to put a modal button/link on each date, just like this:

[image]

The "+" sign, when clicked, should show a modal. Here's my code for that:

```
$( ".fc-day-number" ).append("<a href='' class='addEventBtn' id='modalButton1'>+</a>");
```

When I click a "+" sign, it doesn't show a modal because the `id` attribute is repeated on each date. I inspected the element and found this:

[image]

That's why the modal isn't showing because an `id` attribute value should be unique. Now, I tried another code:

```
for (i=1; i <= 31; i++) {
    $( ".fc-day-number" ).append("<a href='' class='addEventBtn' id='modalButton"+i+"'>+</a>");
}
```

But looks like this now:

[image]

As you can see, it has multiple "+" signs on one date.

So my problem is, how do I put just one "+" sign on each date with unique `id` attribute value?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.fc-day-number').each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).append("<a href='' class='addEventBtn' id='modalButton"+index+"'>+</a>");
});
```

What this does is from the set of matched `.fc-day-number` elements i.e. for each date, it appends a '+' to them with unique id.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your modal open code into dayClick event of fullcalendar like in example :-

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        // do your modal open code here
    }
});
```

It will help you.